# Other methods than SMTP or Office.Interop to send a mail with .net

Tags: c#, vb.net, email, outlook, smtp

I'm looking for an other method to send a mail without using the namespaces `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` or `System.Net.Mail`.

I don't want to use the Outlook Method as this would require and open and logged in Outlook session on the server the script is running on.

Also I can't use the smtpClient-Class as our firewall blocks interactions with other SMTP server (what it is intended to do and we wont change this fact)

Is it possible to interact directly with the Exchange Server? Or is there no other method to send mails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're ok with an external Email Service then look for one that offers a Web Service API (which I assume your firewall is ok with).

SendGrid for example: https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Database Mail.
[Click here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/).

Pass your mail list from c# to Database.From there write a procedure to send mail.
We can easily monitor sent mails.

Comment: That uses SMTP too. So if the database is on the same server, this doesn't help.

Comment: Yup...The method might help if DB in different server..Then REST should be the best way @PatrickHofman